# How to make kdeplot robust to negative/zero values

Tags: python, seaborn, kdeplot

I have two real/float variables stored in native python lists:

```
x = [2.232, 2.331, 2.112...]
y = [-3.431, 2.213, -1.232...]
```

Notice that there are negative values. This seems to be giving the `kde` call some problems. I have gotten this error:

> ZeroDivisionError: 0.0 cannot be raised to a negative power.

For my purposes, the plot doesn't need to be insanely accurate, so I attempted to add in a small amount ad hoc to both `x` and `y`:

```
x = []
for i in range(len(raw_data)):
    x.append(float(raw_data[i][1])+.000000001)
```

To my surprise, the error persisted. I even added a much larger amount (.1) but no progress was made with that either.

### Question

Is there a more fool-proof way to ensure the `kde` call is implemented robust to non-zero entries? The fact that altering my data ad hoc didn't work suggests that something else may be wrong here.

**Call**

```
seaborn.kdeplot(x,y)
```

**Error text**

```
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\nonparametric\bandwidths.py in bw_scott(x, kernel)
     53     A = _select_sigma(x)
     54     n = len(x)
---> 55     return 1.059 * A * n ** (-0.2)
     56 
     57 def bw_silverman(x, kernel=None):
```

Comment: Could you add some code of how exactly you call which kde?  Is this just `sns.kdeplot(x=x, y=y)`?  Why should such give a problem with zeros or negative values? It would only be a problem to use them together with a log scale axis. Or are you using the same values for the x and the y vector? Could you add a full error trace (as text) to your post? Preferably together with some reproducible test data.

Comment: @JohanC That must have slipped my mind, updated, just a standard call as far as I know.

Comment: You need `seaborn.kdeplot(x=x,y=y)`.  `seaborn.kdeplot(x,y)` would result in a type error in the latest seaborn version, and to something strange in older versions.  Note that simply the error message isn't enough to know what's going on. A full trace would be recommended.